# What modules are required to make a seating chart website?

Tags: 7, commerce

I'm currently working on a site that wants to sell theater seating by section by clicking on a map overview of the seats like the one below. What drupal 7 modules are there or recipes that can be done to create this similar functionality?

[image]

Comment: Did you search for modules on drupal.org? What did you find, and what was not helpful for you?

Comment: I want to add to what @kiamlaluno meant by his comment, just in case you missed it.  your question right now is HUGE. you're asking someone to do a TON of research for you.  It's not a specific question and you're not suck on a particular technical detail.  This forum is not set up to answer a question like that.  Also, I think it's a bit dumb to expect people give you that much work for free.

Comment: no i thought there might have been a module that already exists to do something to this extent out of the box. i wasn't expecting anyone to do any work just to answer this question. im posting this question up to see if there was anyone that did a similar site and how they went about doing it. I'm not asking anyone to do the work from scratch. sorry if it came out that way as obviously that was not my intention.

Comment: FWIW I went hunting for a module to do exactly the same thing 2 days ago - didn't find anything

Comment: Clive is right. I have done a ton of searching in this realm and didn't find anything useful.

Comment: good to know. i guess this would have to be done from scratch. i'll post my solution once thats done.

Comment: Talking about doing "research" (as in some previous comments), and since the title includes "chart", I thought it might help to point to https://www.drupal.org/node/2363985 (= current result of "my" research about charting modules). Anybody interested in going over the dozens of charting modules mentioned there? To see if any if it would help to find an appropriate module to solve this "challenging" question, and then publish a real answer here? Please? As Alan Bean (Apollo 12) would say "There HAS to be a way to do this (i.e. 'a' charting module) ..."! PS: why not EDIT the question also?

Answer (score 1):

Closest things I was able to find are [Wysiwyg Image Map](https://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg_imgmap) and [jQuery Map Hilight](https://drupal.org/project/jq_maphilight) modules.

[Wysiwyg Image Map](https://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg_imgmap) is *image Map editor for tinymce provided by the Wysiwyg module.*

[jQuery Map Hilight](https://drupal.org/project/jq_maphilight) *enables the simple addition of mouseover highlighting of hotspots to HTML image maps without requiring the editing of theme files or knowledge of javascript/jquery.*

Together they should give you roughly what you need - but if I were in your situation, I would prefer to code this myself.